# bootstrap grid offset gap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row clearfix">
<div id="a" class="col-md-9">a</div>
<div id="b" class="col-md-2  col-md-offset-1">b</div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#a{
background-color:pink;
}
#b{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

The gap between a and b is too long i want it to shrink to some extent

http://www.bootply.com/HXOMIZHz5x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply give you own width

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mhs33kdt/)**

```
#a {
    background-color:pink;
    width:200px;
}
#b {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:200px;
}
```

Hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: I want two columns within a row itself

Comment: means you want to join it?